# Force table* to stay in the current page

Tags: tables, two-column

I have a wide table in my two-column paper. When I use `\begin{table*}` instead of `\begin{table}`, although the table becomes on wide, but it goes to the next page and I have limit on the number of pages. Is is possible to force my table to be on the same page it is referred? I read [How to force a figure and a table to stay on the same page in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111565/how-to-force-a-figure-and-a-table-to-stay-on-the-same-page-in-latex) and [Get a table and figure on the same page with captions & labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111110/get-a-table-and-figure-on-the-same-page-with-captions-labels) and searched a lot but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if for your table is enough space after the point of its insertion, the package `stfloats` can help you.

Answer (score 5):

`table*` always goes, at the earliest, on the *next* page, simply add it to the source on the page earlier than you want it to appear.